# I want a language recommendation for media development

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I´m a beginner coder. I recently started to learn coding at college. I want to build some projects on my own and I was wondering what language is easy to learn and gets the job done of making a basic website. I´ve learned the basics of HTML, CSS and some Javascript. Are there any more languages I need to know?

Answer (score -1):

I've been a coder for over a decade. For websites HTML5 is the most used language. It's really easy to learn and one of the best languages. CSS is one of many styling languages, CSS is also easy to learn. It's the styling language I recommend the most for beginners.
Javascript is a little harder to learn. It isn't to complex. But I recommend CoffeeScript.
This language is transcomplied into JS. What it does is improving readability of JavaScript and making the code simpler and shorter.

And I also wanna say this: you don't have to learn all languages to be a good programmer. You can also specialise in a couple languages.

Comment: CoffeeScript is just a prettier JavaScript. It will let you have smaller and more readable code by taking core elements of JavaScript and giving you a better way of writing it. CoffeeScript tries to be nicer JavaScript, and to keep the output code similar to the input so that debugging is trivial. <== This text is harder to misunderstand. Also I'd ditch the last paragraph and correct these spelling errors: to -> too, transcomplied -> compiled and Javascript -> JavaScript. You might get an accept vote that way and then I'll upvote and reverse whoever downvoted this answer.